# React - Changing Body Styles with Selectors?

Tags: css, reactjs

I was wondering on how to use CSS selectors within inline styling for React?

```
<style>{'body { color: white; }'}</style>
```

This code makes all of the text within my page white, however, if I wanted to make it so that p tags and a tags have different colors, how would I go about implementing it?

```
<style>{'body p { color: white; }'}</style>
```

This code only chooses the p tags within the current page, for example, leaving the navbar text as black.

Comment: Hi! Why would you like to use inline styles? Those are global declarations for `p` and for `a`.

Comment: I recommend you to review the css selectors and how they work.

Comment: So I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, however im passing in 3 colors from a database, and through these colors, I want to style the page dynamically, so one background color and one p color and one a color.